# Arbitrary sieving: Scenario 2.

Tags: number-theory

This is the second of two related, but distinct, questions that are puzzling me at present.

The sieve of Eratosthanes operates by casting out from the list of natural numbers first every other number, then every third number, then every fifth number, etc. for all prime numbers. In each step, the starting point is the prime number itself, and that starting number does not get cast out. Each step discards $\frac{1}{p}$ of the numbers in the list, retaining $1-\frac{1}{p}$ of the numbers. One might naively intuit that if the starting list contained the numbers $1$ to $k$, and one sieved with every prime less than or equal to $k$, the sieved list would contain $k\prod(1-\frac{1}{p})$ numbers, but this is not the case.

The reason given for why this is not the case is that after one selects a first prime number to sieve with, the selection of subsequent sieving numbers is not entirely independent. In short, the second selected prime is constrained in that it must be coprime to the first selected prime, and the third selected prime is doubly encumbered in this sense. In general the $n+1$st selected prime is subject to $n$ such coprimality contraints. Since the prime numbers used as the basis for sieving are not strictly independently chosen, $k\prod(1-\frac{1}{p})$ does not give a correct count of numbers on the sieved list.

Now we introduce an arbitrary change. Instead of using prime numbers, we randomly pick numbers $1<a_i\le k$ from the original list as the basis for sieving. In order to make the comparison uniform and relevant to the Eratosthanes case, we select $n$ such numbers, where $n: p_n\le k<p_{n+1}$. For each $a_i$, we remove all multiples of $a_i$ (except $a_i$ itself) from the list. Each such step discards a fraction $\frac{1}{a_i}$ of the members of the list, leaving a fraction $1-\frac{1}{a_i}$. Because the ${a_i}$ are independently selected, it should be the case that the count of numbers in the sieved list is $k\prod(1-\frac{1}{a_i})$.

Of course, in any particular case, this approach to sieving tells us essentially nothing except what is the case for some arbitrarily chosen set of ${a_i}$. We don't know what numbers are left, or how many of them there are without actually working it out for individual instances. On the other hand, if this arbitrary sieving process were performed a large number of times, each time with a newly chosen set of $a_i$,there might be some stochastic trend or characteristic of the results taken cumulatively. For example, there might be a most probable count of numbers on such a sieved list. If so, that most probable count might bear some relationship to $\pi(k)$. I have no reason to believe any of that is the case, but I am curious.

I would imagine that for any claimed result to be convincing, the size of $k$ would have to be modestly large ($10^5$?), and the number of repetitions of the sieve with arbitrarily selected sets of $a_i$ would have to be similarly large. Such computations, and the computer chops to program them, are well beyond my capabilities.

Question 1: Am I correct in concluding that the count of numbers in the sieved list is $k\prod(1-\frac{1}{a_i})$?

Question 2: Is there anyone with the skills, interest and time who would look into the stochastic behavior of this sort of arbitrary sieve, and report her/his findings in an answer to this post?

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/3029322?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @KeithBackman When you randomly pick the numbers $1 \lt a_i \le k$ and use them, how do you handle cases where $a_i \mid a_j$ for some $i \lt j$? Do you remove $a_j$ or leave it because it's one of the numbers you picked? As for your statement "Because the ${a_i}$ are independently selected, it should be the case that the count of numbers in the sieved list is $k\prod(1-\frac{1}{a_i})$", this will not generally be true. This is because even with independently selected values, there'll be some cases where a value to remove has already been removed, i.e., where $a_i$ & $a_j$ divide a value. ...

Comment: @KeithBackman (cont.) Nonetheless, I believe the final number of values will generally be larger than the number of primes because your set of values will repeat certain prime factors & have certain primes not be included at all, so some of the values with only prime factors among these excluded set of primes will be left. As such, I think another appropriate & interesting question will be how, on average, the count of these sieved lists compare to the number of primes.